# CSS Grid - Using auto fill columns with minmax

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to understand why the individual column width is showing up as 117.5px in firefox inspector when I have set the min width of column to 100px and the max is 1fr. Shouldn't each column be 100px instead ? With auto fill, why is the grid trying to fill up the remaining container space ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
<style>
  .grid {
    width: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template: 50px 50px / repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    border: 2px solid red;
  }

  .item {
    background: #ccc;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Firefox inspector screenshot]

Comment: no, if you want 100px you use `50px 50px / repeat(auto-fill, 100px)` .. minmax(100px,1fr) will try to fill all the space while not getting under 100px